# Regex with wildcards and slashes?

Tags: regex, grep, notepad++

I'm using WinGrep and Notepad++ (Windows) with some other software that uses Regex.
I've also been attempting to solve it with this site:-
http://www.regexlab.com/wild2regex

An example of the text I'm working with is here:-

---

```
newmtl models\cat1\item1
    illum 1
    Kd 1 1 1
    map_Kd models\cat1\item1.dds

newmtl models\cat1\item2
    illum 1
    Kd 1 1 1
    map_Kd models\cat1\item2.dds

newmtl models\cat1\item3
    illum 1
    Kd 1 1 1
    map_Kd models\cat1\item3.dds
```

---

I would like to change the back-slashes on the header lines "newmtl" to forward-slashes, without affecting the lower "map_Kd" line.
The "models cat# item#" could be anything, these are all wildcards with any letter or number, possibly with underscores and exclamation marks.
This is really difficult for me since it not only involves returning multiple wildcards but also working with special characters.

Any help would be deeply appreciated! :)

Comment: What is the pattern that does not work?

Comment: For example:- search "newmtl (?:(?!\\)(?:.|\n))+\\(?:(?!\\)(?:.|\n))+\\", replace "newmtl (?:(?!/)(?:.|\n))+/(?:(?!/)(?:.|\n))+/"...  yes, clearly I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: It does not look even valid. Try ``(?:\G(?!^)|^newmtl )[^\\\r\n]*\K\\`` and replace with `/` in Notepad++. It will work even if the number of ``\`` chars is variable on each line.

Comment: If you are using ``newmtl (?:(?!\\)(?:.|\n))+\\(?:(?!\\)(?:.|\n))+\\`` you just miss the capturing groups and replace with backreference.  See the answer below. However, never use `(?:.|\n)`, use `.` and the dotall modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using NP++ this should work.

Find `(?m)(?:^\h*newmtl|\G(?!^))[^\\\r\n]*\K\\`
Replace `/`

http://rubular.com/r/IG0yMflzIa

Readable version

```
 (?m)                    # Multi-line mode
 (?:                     # ------------
      ^ \h*                   # BOL and optional horizontal whitespace
      newmtl  
   |                        # or,
      \G                      # Anchor, start this match where last left off
      (?! ^ )                 # Except if its BOL
 )                       # ------------
 [^\\\r\n]*              # Anything but \ or CRLF, stay on this line
 \K                      # Ignore all that matched up to here
 \\                      # The only thing that is left, will be replaced
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems simple enough. In Notepad++, simply run

Find what: `(newmtl .+?)\\(.+?)\\(.+?)`

Replace with: `$1/$2/$3`